# HMAC MD5 Validation with Node.js, Express and Trialpay

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, express

I'm trying to authenticate a message sent from TrialPay using Node.js and Express. TrialPay signs requests with an HMAC-MD5 hash, and provides [these instructions](https://merchant.trialpay.com/help/?page=hmac) on validating.

This is my code:

```
app.post('/trialpay', function(req, res) {

    var key = "[MY MERCHANT KEY]";
    var hash = req.header("TrialPay-HMAC-MD5");
    var data = req.body.toString();

    var crypted = require("crypto").createHmac("md5", key)
        .update(data)
        .digest("hex");

    if (hash == crypted) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "plain/text"});
        res.end("Success!");
    } else {
        throw new Error("Invalid TrialPay Hash");
    }  
});
```

This is, obviously, not working (hash doesn't match).

Disclaimer: I'm extremely new to Node.js, and have little Javascript experience, to begin with.

**UPDATE**

I did not realize that the link was protected.

> TrialPay uses your Notification-Key (set in your account information)
>   as the secret key to sign the HMAC. For GET requests the query string
>   that follows the question mark (in the URL) is signed. For POST
>   requests the entire POST body is signed.

Here is an example of how TrialPay instructs you to validate in Google App Engine (Python):

```
class MyHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
  key = '[YOUR MERCHANT KEY]'
  tphash = self.request.headers['TrialPay-HMAC-MD5'] 
  if hmacmd5(key,self.request.body) != tphash:
    logging.info('invalid trialpay hash')
    return
```

**UPDATE 2**

The `req.body` prints out as:

```
{ 
  oid: 'sample-order-id',
  sid: 'customer-sid',
  order_date: '04/24/2012',
  timestamp: '04/24/2012 16:28:46',
  first_name: 'customer-firstname',
  last_name: 'customer-lastname',
  email: 'customer@trialpay.com',
  revenue: '10.00',
  zip_code: '94041',
  country: 'US' 
}
```

Comment: Your link doesn't work -- it won't let me log in. That said, you should stay clear of `throw`ing inside your request handlers (basically, anywhere in node). Accept the third parameter (the callback, `next` in express lingo) and pass the error to `next` instead. Or even better, handle the error here, where you can, and `res.send(403, 'Invalid TrialPay Hash')`. Also, you don't mention what kind of data you are posting -- it would be interesting to see what `req.body` and especially `req.body.toString()` contains, if you could `console.log` that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and advice @LinusGThiel. When I tried `console.log(req.body.toString());` it only prints out "[object Object]". Please excuse my ignorance, here.

Comment: That's what I suspected! What does `console.log(req.body)` give you?

Comment: You are filling in [MY MERCHANT KEY] with the correct data, right?

Comment: Okay, `console.log(req.body)` gives me back the list of JSON parameters. So, how do I pass this to `crypto.update()`? It needs a String or Buffer. I tried both (perhaps incorrectly) and neither worked.

Comment: Forgot to tag @LinusGThiel in the last comment. (Also updated question)

Comment: Hi @iPaulPro, I can't say what you should send to TrialPay -- as I said, I can't access the documentation. Perhaps they want it as JSON, or perhaps as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: @LinusGThiel I am responding to a POST from TrialPay, not sending one. They send JSON and I am trying to verify the source by comparing an HMAC-MD5 of the request body. I am able to parse the JSON and extract params directly from `req.body`. Now I need to pass that JSON as a String or Buffer to `var crypted = require("crypto").createHmac("md5", key).update(**data**).digest("hex");`. `JSON.stringify()` and `toString()` did not work. I've updated the answer with the JSON returned.

Comment: I get that you're receiving from TrialPay, sorry about that. Anyway, my guess is that when express does a `JSON.parse` of the POST body, and you then `JSON.stringify` it, the order of the parameters change and then, of course, the md5 will be different. Try using `req.rawBody` directly: `crypto.createHmac("md5", key).update(req.rawBody).digest("hex")`. (Express stores the original POST body in `req.rawBody`).

Comment: Ah I found this -- seems `req.rawBody` has disappeared. See the comments of this issue: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/897

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

function calculateSignature(key) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        var hash = req.header("TrialPay-HMAC-MD5"),
            hmac = crypto.createHmac("md5", key);

        req.on("data", function(data) {
            hmac.update(data);
        });

        req.on("end", function() {
            var crypted = hmac.digest("hex");

            if(crypto.timingSafeEqual(
              Buffer.from(crypted),
              Buffer.from(hash.padEnd(crypted.length))
            )) {
                // Valid request
                return res.send("Success!", { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
            } else {
                // Invalid request
                return res.send("Invalid TrialPay hash", { "Content-Type": "text/plain" }, 403);
            }
        });

        req.on("error", function(err) {
            return next(err);
        });
    }
}

app.post("/trialpay", calculateSignature("[MY MERCHANT KEY]"));
```

Comment: This is working!! Thanks so much for you help. Just one issue, I added `res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'plain/text'});` above `res.end("Success!")` because the TrialPay server is just hanging. I logged the hash and they match, so I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: Great! It's actually not a `res.end` but a `res.send` -- a goodie from Express. See [res.send documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#res.send%28%29). Wow, looking at that, I see that strings will always be send with `Content-Type: text/html`. My bad. Updated above.

Comment: I only changed it to `end` because `send` was hanging, too. I tried `console.log('Success!');` in the `app.post()` above `res.send("Success!");` and nothing was logged.

Comment: Ok then it doesn't arrive to the route for some reason. Hmm. Well, if you just need it for one route you don't have to have it as a middleware, and can just respond directly instead. Might be better. Also, you *never* want to `require` in async code (request handlers, middlewares and so on) because `require` is synchronous. Moved that up to the top scope instead.

Comment: Tried the updated answer, still hanging. The issue is somehow `if(crypted === hash)`. I logged both hashes, and they definitely match, but when I tried logging `console.log('Hashes match!');` in that `if` statement, it is never printed.

Comment: Ok. I used the non-coercive equals `===` just to be sure, but they *should* both be strings. Can you `console.log(crypted, typeof crypted)` and do the same for `hash`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10510/discussion-between-ipaulpro-and-linus-g-thiel)

Comment: It works (fully)!! Just needed to alter the usage of `express.bodyParser()`, as directed by the github link provided. Thanks a million @LinusGThiel!!

Comment: This is vulnerable to timing attacks. You should ensure that the comparison `crypted === hash` takes constant time regardless of how many bytes of them match.

Answer (score -1):

For Parse Cloud Code:(I have tested)
The point is express.bodyParser will parse the url encoded string which is used to hash.

```
var parseExpressRawBody = require('parse-express-raw-body');
var queryString = require('querystring');
app.post('/trialpay',parseExpressRawBody(),function(req, res) {
var hmac, calculatedSignature,payloadStr=req.body.toString();
hmac = crypto.createHmac('md5', TrialPayMerchentKey);
hmac.update(payloadStr);
calculatedSignature = hmac.digest('hex');

if (req.headers['trialpay-hmac-md5'] === calculatedSignature) {
   ~~~~~~
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: Your snippet is truly bad. What should it do? Take a time to review your message before posting it.