# Node.js - req.on("data") in POST is never called even though req.body is not empty

Tags: node.js, post, hmac

I'm doing the following :

```
......
....
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({  
  extended: true 
})); 

app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.post('/uninstalled', function (req, res, next)
{     
  var bodyAsQueryString = queryString.stringify(req.body);
  console.log('bodyAsQueryString = ' + bodyAsQueryString);

  var hmacReceived = req.headers['x-shopify-hmac-sha256'];
  var calculatedHmac = crypto.createHmac('SHA256', config.app.secret);

  req.on("data", function(data) 
  {
     console.log('on data...');
     calculatedHmac.update(data);
  });

  req.on("end", function() 
  {
     console.log('on end...');
     calculatedHmac = calculatedHmac.digest("base64");
     console.log('hmacReceived = ' + hmacReceived);
     console.log('calculatedHmac = ' + calculatedHmac);
  });

  req.on("error", function(err) 
  {
     console.log('on error...');
     console.log(err);
     return next(err);
  });
});
```

None of the above `req.on("...")` is ever called (nothing is console-logged...) - What am I doing wrong ?

The value of `bodyAsQueryString` always looks smth like the following (I've replaced personal data with `xxxxx`) :

> id=xxxxx&name=xxxxx&email=xxxxxx&domain=xxxxxxx&created_at=2015-03-21T00%3A31%3A36%2B00%3A00&province=&country=GB&address1=xxxxxxxxx&zip=E59JY&city=London&source=xxxx&phone=xxxxxx&updated_at=2015-08-19T15%3A12%3A31%2B01%3A00&customer_email=&latitude=xxxxx&longitude=-xxxxxx&primary_location_id=&primary_locale=en&country_code=GB&country_name=United%20Kingdom&currency=USD&timezone=(GMT%2B00%3A00)%20Europe%2FLondon&iana_timezone=Europe%2FLondon&shop_owner=xxxxxx&money_format=%24%20%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D&money_with_currency_format=%24%20%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D%20USD&province_code=&taxes_included=false&tax_shipping=&county_taxes=true&plan_display_name=affiliate&plan_name=affiliate&myshopify_domain=xxxxxx.myshopify.com&google_apps_domain=&google_apps_login_enabled=&money_in_emails_format=%24%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D&money_with_currency_in_emails_format=%24%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D%20USD&eligible_for_payments=false&requires_extra_payments_agreement=false&password_enabled=true&has_storefront=true&setup_required=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the raw POST body rather than req.body.

Try something like this:

```
app.post('/somepath', function (req, res, next) {
    var hmacReceived = req.headers['x-shopify-hmac-sha256'];
    hmac = crypto.createHmac('SHA256',secret);

    req.on("data", function(data) {
        hmac.update(data);
    });

    req.on("end", function() {
        var calculatedHmac = hmac.digest("base64");
        var test1 = hmacReceived === calculatedHmac;
    });

    req.on("error", function(err) {
        return next(err);
    });
}
```

Further details in this similar question:

[HMAC MD5 Validation with Node.js, Express and Trialpay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305067/hmac-md5-validation-with-node-js-express-and-trialpay)

Comment: I see you already fixed the hex to base64, which is also needed (shopify uses b64 in some cases and hex in others)

Comment: Apologies @davesatch but while you were writing this I fixed everything (having done a bit more research on the subject) but I'm still getting errors - see my updates in my OP.

Comment: Sure, you have two methods there now, the use and the post. Does it work if you replace your app.post method with mine?

Comment: I just tried that. I removed my top `app.use(function` and actually used the function like you do in your post from within `app.post(....`. Unfortunately, `req.on("end)` (maybe even `req.on("data")`) never gets called. Even though I've verified that the body is not empty.

Comment: `req.on("error"` isn't called either - just the top 2 lines of code in `app.post(` are executed

Comment: Code looks okay, can only think it might be something on the syntax: 1) have you added "next" after req and res in the function arguments as in my example. 2) do you have crypto defined somewhere, such as `var crypto = require('crypto');` on a line before the app.post 3) is secret actually defined as something? i.e. "my-secret". Another option is to paste in the accepted answer from the question I linked and see if you have any luck.

Comment: 1), 2) & 3) are all OK  -  I've just realised that further up in my code I'm doing `app.use(bodyParser.json()); app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})); ` could this be an issue ?

Comment: Nope I removed `app.user(bodyParser...` and `req.on("...")` are still never called (none of them) even though `bodyAsQueryString` is always populated. This is really weird..

Comment: Turns outs it's because I wasn't replying to the client anywhere in the callback (either from inside `req.on()` or at the end of the callback) which is weird because it seems to be specific to `req.on(..)` as other parts of the code execute..

Answer (score 0):

Turns outs it's because I wasn't replying to the client anywhere in the callback with something like:

```
res.sendStatus(200); or res.sendStatus(500); etc...
```

It's weird because my the code in my callbacks executes fine (even without ever replying to the client) but apparently
if the node parser realises there is a `req.on()` and no reply to the client, either inside or outside of it, it will ignore the `req.on(..)` which makes no sense really... Either the whole thing should break or none of it if a reply to the client is missing.